# How can I get and remove the first element from a data structure?

Tags: java, list, set

I need to use a data structure which can -

- maintain the insertion order.
- do not store any duplicates.
- And I can easily get and remove first element from it efficiently.

Below is my code which uses LinkedList but it doesn't filter out any duplicates. And it has `removeFirst()` method which gets and remove the first element in a list.

```
public static LinkedList<String> getData(TypeEnum types) {
    LinkedList<String> listOfPaths = new LinkedList<String>();
    String prefix = types.equals(TypeEnum.PARTIAL) ? TypeEnum.PARTIAL.value() : TypeEnum.UNPARTIAL.value();
    listOfPaths.add(prefix + LOCAL_PATH); // first element in the list is always LOCAL PATH
    for (String path : REMOTE_PATH) {
        listOfPaths.add(prefix + path);
    }
    return listOfPaths;
}
```

Below is how I am using `getData` method:

```
LinkedList<String> data = getData(types);
String local_path = data.removeFirst(); // this is my local path
// use local_path here

// now iterate all the remote path
for(String remotePath : data) {
    // do something with remotePath
}
```

What are the options I have here which will be efficient? Does any other data structure can do the same thing by avoiding the duplicates. I know Set can do that, but Set doesn't have any `removeFirst` method and not sure whether it's a right structure to use here. Also, Can anyone provide an example as well.

Comment: A linked hash set will maintain the insertion order and eliminate duplicates. You could get and remove the first element by using an iterator to  identify the first object, then using it or calling remove(Object) to remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) (maintains insertion order). For instance, add the items first to this `Set` to filter out duplicates, then add all the items into the `LinkedList`:

```
public static LinkedList<String> getData(TypeEnum types) {
    LinkedList<String> listOfPaths = new LinkedList<String>();
    LinkedHashSet<String> uniques = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    String prefix = types.equals(TypeEnum.PARTIAL) ? TypeEnum.PARTIAL.value() : TypeEnum.UNPARTIAL.value();
    uniques.add(prefix + LOCAL_PATH); // first element in the list is always LOCAL PATH
    for (String path : REMOTE_PATH) {
        uniques.add(prefix + path);
    }
    listOfPaths.addAll(uniques);
    return listOfPaths;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer was fixed according to @copeg comments, thanks.

The solution could be to just simply extend the list add method by doing something like this:

```
public class MyList<E> extends LinkedList<E> {
     @Override
     public boolean add(int index, E element){
        if(this.contains(element))return false;
        return super.add(index,element);
    }

}
```

Comment: A `SortedSet` is sorted by the natural ordering of its elements (or provided Comparator), not insertion order (first requirement by OP).

Comment: Yeah you are right, see the other poposal. From the other side, what about providing a compatator that would always return 0 to keep the ordering unchanged?

Comment: RE your second approach, I'd recommend overriding the `add(int index, E element)` method, as `add(E element)` (or other internal methods that can add to the List) delegate to the two parameter method

Comment: Thanks for comments. I've fixed my answer to refled them.